# Why are odd-degreed polynomial kernels slower than those with even degrees for SVM?

Tags: classification, svm, kernel-trick, polynomial, one-class

I have been using one-class support vector classifiers to extract features for multinomial classification. I noticed that fitting time is much longer when the degree of the polynomial kernel is odd. For instance, a 10th-degree polynomial kernel is much faster than a 7th-degree polynomial kernel. I suspect the even-degreed polynomial kernels are faster because the signs cancel or something like that.

Could someone please explain to me intuitively why there is such a speed difference?

I am using scikit-learn's implementation and Python 3.8.